# How many words consisting of 8 letters, where the letters are A, B, C and D can be made?

Tags: combinatorics

The specific question is:
 - $A$ must be the first letter
 - The word must contain exactly 2 $C$'s

The solution to the problem is:
$1{7\choose 2}3^5$

I understand the first and third factor of the solution. But I do not understand the second factor of the solution. Why is it ${7\choose2}$?

My solution to the problem would have been: $1{4\choose1}{4\choose1}3^5$
if I did it according to my understanding?

Could someone please explain me where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that the solution said $\binom{8}{2}$ and not $\binom{7}{2}$? Then the solution would make sense to me. (1st spot is for the $A$, next 7 are free. Pick exactly two of the seven spots for $C$'s, the other 5 are for the other three letters, hence $3^5$.)

Comment: @aras: Yes you were right, I managed to type in the wrong solution, I have now edited, thank you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the solution should have been $\binom{7}{2}$:

There is 1 way to pick $A$'s spot.

There are $\binom{7}{2}$ ways to pick exactly two spots of the remaining 7 for the $C$'s.

There are $3^5$ ways to label the remaining five spots with the 3 remaining letters $A$, $B$ and $D$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, now it makes sense :D